# How to match the account seed, such that find_program_address, will generate thesame program-address as create_account_with_seed

Tags: python, solana

I have this piece of Code:

```
seed = "hello-world"
greeted, nonce = PublicKey.find_program_address(seeds=[bytes(seed, 'utf8')], program_id=program_id)

params = system_program.CreateAccountWithSeedParams(from_pubkey = keypair.public_key, new_account_pubkey = greeted, base_pubkey=keypair.public_key, lamports=2000, program_id = program_id, seed={'length': len(seed), 'chars':seed}, space = 8 )

transaction_params = system_program.create_account_with_seed(params)

transaction = Transaction()
transaction.add(transaction_params)
client.send_transaction(transaction, keypair)
```

everything runs just fine, up until the last line, where we get an error,

** 'Create: address 9sqS4pfUyJgC6S6bkTKjdVE7bXbhrThy89JnseatZFQ6 does not match derived address EKPQ19iekuscpWXLv1pQ7Swd8fVxDinWXcLZrdxBnsPN' **

the reason I think is very obvious, which is that it perceives the seed ununiformly across find_program_address, and create_account_with_seed, and hence the resulting addresses are different.

So my question is, How do I structure the seed, so that it matches both methods, to yield thesame *program-address*

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you need to use `PublicKey.create_with_seed` if you want to create the account with seed, rather than using `PublicKey.find_program_address`.  The function is at https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/blob/eb03b092a9a013578caab2e7a07ebcb5e44d84d1/src/solana/publickey.py#L71

If you want to create an account at a program address, you need to create a program which will use `invoke_signed` on the program address, providing the seeds used to derive the address.

Here's an example with `create_with_seed`: https://solanacookbook.com/recipes/accounts.html#create-account-with-seed

Here's an example with `find_program_address`: https://solanacookbook.com/recipes/accounts.html#program-derived-address